# Why are my ice cubes sticking in their containers?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, ice, freezing

I make my ice in those little round to-go containers that usually hold sauces/dressings.
When using the clear containers, the ice sticks to it and requires heat or violence to get it out. When I use the black containers, the ice slides right out with no fuss. Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 1):

Your evidence indicates without question that the two materials are not the same; here is why it's important.

Think of water as if it were paint. You paint a surface with water and if the water fails to *wet* that surface, it pulls together into individual droplets and does not stick to it to form a uniform film that bonds to the surface. If the water *wets* the surface, then the droplets spread out into a film that coats the surface, and that water *sticks* to the surface.

Then imagine freezing that water. If the water does not stick to the surface, then it will break loose easily when frozen into ice and the cubes pop loose easily from the tray. If the water does stick to the surface, then so will the ice and the cubes won't pop loose easily from the tray.

This indicates that the water does not wet the two different container surfaces to the same extent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are the materials of the two containers the same?

Let's assume that both are made of plastic: minerals such as calcium carbonate that are commonly found in water tend to get stuck in plastic containers or trays. These stuck minerals cling to the water molecules you want to freeze, bonding together and making the ice stick. A simple solution would be to (1) clean the trays thoroughly after every freeze, (2) pre-boil the water before freezing to prevent air pockets from forming in your ice and (3) avoid over-filling your container (in the condition of ice trays).

An elaboration on the sticking of ice (when it sticks to your fingers or your tongue when you touch it): The warmth of your body parts melts the ice when you touch it. However, because of the general cold temperature of the ice, the ice-turned-water almost immediately freezes back into ice, therefore creating a bond between your finger or tongue and the ice.

Hope this helps ;)